# AS 3.0 Creating instances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I started programming with Java, then I moved to as 3.0 to enhance my experience in UI.

Something I don't get in as 3.0 is the difference between MovieClip Object and instance.

To clarify, because I don't know if I have used the correct terminology:

The difference between: `var name : ObjectName = new ClassName();` and the movie clip created on stage and give it an instance name.

I assume there are differences because I can use assign the movie clip's instance to the tween's object parameter, but cannot assign the one defined using variable.

I don't know if I am making any sense, but thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A MovieClip is one of three types of symbols available in Flash.  Those three are MovieClip, Graphic, and Button. All MovieClip and Button symbols have the ability to have instance names set for them so that you can reference them from your ActionScript code. If you choose not to set an instance name for a Button or a MovieClip, Flash will automatically assign an instance name to it during runtime, regardless if you plan on referencing it from your ActionScript.

So for arguments sake, let's say you have a MovieClip on the stage with an instance name of "my_icon_mc". You could reference it in your code like so:

By calling the instance name itself, "my_icon_mc", or by storing a reference to it in a variable like so: (doing it this way has many advantages)

```
var myIcon:MovieClip = my_icon_mc;
```

In this example, I am storing a reference to a MovieClip on the stage with an instance name of "my_icon_mc" in the variable named `myIcon`.  This allows me now to use the various MovieClip methods and properties of the MovieClip class in my code to manipulate the MovieClip on the stage.

So let's say I want to change the x coordinate of my movieclip on the stage to be at point 100, I could do the following:

```
my_icon_mc.x = 100
```

**OR**

```
var myIcon:MovieClip = my_icon_mc;
myIcon.x = 100;
```

It is important to note that if you create MovieClip via ActionScript, you can set the instance name of that MovieClip by using the name property of the MovieClip class like so:

```
var myIcon:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
myIcon.name = 'my_icon_mc';
```

Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html